# Outputting correctly a very long textarea value in PHP

Tags: php

I have a textarea with input like this:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
```

I want an output with line breaks like this:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

How can I do that?

In my previous question, someone suggested `wordwrap`, which would be useful if the line had spaces.

Comment: You can do it with manual word wrap.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. What should happen with this very long string? Split up into multiple lines?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use [wordwrap](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)...

```
$text = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 10, "<br />", true);
echo $newtext;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand the question correctly, but HTML textarea field also has the wrap attribute (values "soft", "hard", or "off"). Hard wraps the words inside the text box and places line breaks at the end of each line so that when the form is submitted it appears exactly as it does in the text box.

So:

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="5" wrap="hard">text..</textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

you could insert a "<br />  at the index, where the break should occur - only for the output.

```
textbox.value = HandleLineBreaks(line, index);
```